# LINQ - Where Conditions - "if-else" Cases

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have following Linq query. What I want is if I do search for a particular `year`, I should get corresponding records of that `year`. Else just show records of current year. Same way `searchtext` has also to be done.

```
    public ActionResult Search(string searchtext, int? year)
    {
                string selyear = year.ToString();
                string curyear = (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString();

                hdms = from t in db.HOLIDAY                           
                       where    
                           (year == null || t.DOH.StartsWith(selyear)) &&
                           (searchtext == "" || t.HOLIDAY_NAME == searchtext)                      
                       select new HOLIDAYDETAILS
                       {
                           DOH = t.DOH,                               
                       };
                       ....
    }
```

I want to satisfy this also `if (year == null) then t.DOH.StartsWith(curyear)` and

`if (searchtext == "") then t.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday" && t.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Saturday"`.

Also If both are null at the same time, both conditions should be satisfied together.

How can I give this one too on the above where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Search(int? year)
{
    string curyear = (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString();
    string selyear = year!=null? year.ToString() : curyear;

    var query = from t in db.HOLIDAY
                join t1 in db.EMPLOYEE on t.UPDATED_BY equals t1.EMP_CODE
                select new {t,t1};

    query = query.Where(o=>o.t.DOH.StartsWith(selyear));

    if (searchtext == "")
    {
        query = query.Where(o=>o.t.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Sunday" && o.t.HOLIDAY_NAME != "Saturday");
    }

    hdms = query.OrderBy(o=>o.t.DOH).Select(o=> new HOLIDAYDETAILS
           {
               DOH = o.t.DOH,                               
           });
   ....
}
```

Comment: Above code worked for me. Can you give me the condition for `searchtext` too?

Comment: @LimnaD'silva you can create query step-by-step depending on your conditions

Answer (score 3):

If checking year is null or not is your problem then you simply can do like this-

```
public ActionResult Search(int? year)
    {
                string selyear = year.ToString();
                string queryyear = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selyear)) // checking for null
                                   ? (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString() // current year
                                   : selyear; // year in query

                hdms = from t in db.HOLIDAY
                       join t1 in db.EMPLOYEE on t.UPDATED_BY equals t1.EMP_CODE
                       where    
                           t.DOH.StartsWith(queryyear)  // comparing queryyear        

                       orderby
                           t.DOH
                       select new HOLIDAYDETAILS
                       {
                           DOH = t.DOH,                               
                       };
                       ....
    }
```

Hope this will works for you...